# How to know when to get on and off for transfers on Greyhound?

Tags: buses, tips-and-tricks, greyhound, novice-travellers

This is my first time riding the Greyhound bus by myself. I'm very scared, I don't know when to get on and off the bus, and I'm also scared to ask for help.
I have two transfers in the whole trip. Would the bus numbers be on the ticket?

Comment: Anything in particular you're afraid of? I have a feeling more questions would be worth asking...

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask. There are always people around that know the answers to your questions. People are always glad to help fellow travellers, so please use their knowledge! Will save you a lot of time :)

Comment: In which country? There are long distance bus/coach companies with the name Greyhound and varying degrees of relatedness and of serivce in several countries. At least Australia, Canada, and the US. Possibly in the UK too. Rather than replying to this comment just edit the info into the question / title / tags.

Answer (score 12):

Generally when you get to the bus station, there'll be a board for information. Failing that, ask at a counter.  One of these two sources will tell you the gate for the bus, based on your destination.

You've not specified your country, but usually the transfers and bus numbers have been on the ticket or receipt, for example:

[image]

([source on joe-orgill.com](http://joe-orgill.com/mexico/slckino2.htm))

The bus drivers are also usually VERY descriptive about every stage, announcing exactly what you have to do, when.  If in doubt, check with the driver - there's always someone clarifying stuff with them, so you won't be alone.